# Счётчик переходов(метрика)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Как реализовать следующее, есть ссылка `http://localhost/siute/ind.php?name=aaa`, 
в файле есть запись

```
<?php
$a=$_GET['name'];
$file='text.txt'; 
file_put_contents($file, $a."\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

Хочу чтобы я находился на данной ссылке `http://localhost/siute/ind.php` и видел как в онлайне либо увеличивался счётчик или просто в строке выдавалось сообщение
 `if($_GET['name']=='aaa'{echo 'Есть посещение из AAA'}`

Comment: Не понятно чего именно вы хотите.
Чтобы вы статично находились на странице и видели увеличение счетчика или появление строки при посещении людьми страницы с именем?
Для этого нужен реактивный фреймворк. Чистый PHP выполняется единоразово при загрузке страницы. Им можно реализовать обновление счетчика только при обновлении вами страницы с счетчиком

Comment: как вариант - задать на js повторение одной и той же функции - обращение к php скрипту в другом файле раз в n секунд. Скрипт должен идти в файл, читать инфу и передавать в ответ.
Оптимально использовать для всего этого не файл, а sql базу

Comment: @Константин да мне надо если данные в базе увеличились на одну строчку или в файле то выходил Alert на какуюнибудь страницу и появлялась запись ниже.

Comment: Тогда давайте по вводным: 1. jQuery приемлим? 2. База или файл? 3. Обновление счётчика раз в несколько секунд подходит? Либо минут?

Comment: @Константин 1. приемлим 2.база mysql 3. 10 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код вашей страницы

```
    <script>


$(document).ready(function(){
    var name= window.location.href.split('?'), resault=0;

    setInterval('chech()',10000);


    });


function check(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',                        
        url: 'check.php',
        data: { 'name':name},    
        response: 'text',
        async:true,                   
        success:function (data) {           
           resault=data;             

            }
        });

    $('#counter').html(resault);
    }


</script>

<body>
    <div>
        <sapan class="name">aaa быд на сайте <span id="counter"></span> раз!</sapan>
    </div>

</body>
```

Код файла check.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$database = "";
$username = "";
$password = "#P4S5";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$conn -> set_charset( 'utf8' );
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM /*таблица*/ WHERE name='".$_GET['name']."'";
 $resault = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($conn));

  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($resault);
  if($rows>0)
  {
    $counter_state =mysqli_fetch_row($resault)+1;

     $query = "UPDATE /*таблица*/ SET `counter` = '".$counter_state."'
       WHERE `name` = '".$_GET['name']."'";
      mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($conn));

      echo($counter_state);
  }
  else
  {

        $query = "INSERT INTO /*таблица*/ (
          `name`,
          `counter`

        )
        VALUES ( 
          '".$_GET['name']."',
          '1'
        )";
    echo(1);
  }

?>
```

Думаю, подключение к jquery и остальной обвес html добавите сами?)

Comment: ок, попробую, позже